# Do you know why the plot-screen don't appear on the pie charm?

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook, imshow

Now, I use pycharm as python-IDE. When I use imshow() from matplotlib, the function works well,but the plot-screen don't appear. 
the plot-screen appear on jupyter notebook.

```
import numpy as np

image = np.array([[[[1],[2],[3]],
                   [[4],[5],[6]], 
                   [[7],[8],[9]]]], dtype=np.float32)
print(image.shape)
plt.imshow(image.reshape(3,3), cmap='Greys')
```

Comment: You need to add more context (code) to this post. It's like saying to a mechanic that " _there is an issue with the car, can you fix it ?_ " then leaving away.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a line from your question `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`. Try adding the line `plt.show()`. Interestingly when I run this from the PyCharm command line I don't need the line, but when I run it in a script I do. I also need the extra line when I run from the linux command line.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

image = np.array([[[[1],[2],[3]],
                   [[4],[5],[6]], 
                   [[7],[8],[9]]]], dtype=np.float32)
print(image.shape)
plt.imshow(image.reshape(3,3), cmap='Greys')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks to your comment! and your code works well! However, plot-screen still don't appear on my pycharm  although I add the code "from matplaot~" except for plot.show(). Like below,                                                    

    import numpy as np 
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    image = np.array([[[[1],[2],[3]],
                       [[4],[5],[6]], 
                       [[7],[8],[9]]]], dtype=np.float32)
    print(image.shape)
    plt.imshow(image.reshape(3,3), cmap='Greys')

Comment: so you didn't try `plt.show()`? It was required for me when I was using it in a script. Try adding it at the bottom and see what happens.